# Power BI filtering issues with matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

Can any one please help me out.

See the attached images.

Matrix in the Power BI will be filtered based on the month selected (Left side visual).
When selected January, in matrix, on expanding the Location R100, there are values for Jan 06, Jan 27 which is correct. But I don’t have to show Jan 13 and Jan 21, because there are no sessions scheduled for those dates. How can i achieve it?

For Locations Del Paso, I don’t have to display any January dates as no sessions happened for those locations on those dates.

[Sample Fact Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOFvH.png)

[PowerBI Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKxfO.png)

[SSAS Tabular Model Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0hDn.png)

[January](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1lbo.png)

[June](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRn3U.png)

SSAS 2017, PBI Sep 2019 versions.

The data source for Power BI report is from the SSAS server.

Thanks,

Vamsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix is only showing the rows if there is a result for that row. You might think: It's 0 so there is no result. But that's wrong: 0 is also a valid result. In order to remove the line, you have to make sure the result is empty, also known as NULL in databases and BLANK in DAX.

Since you didn't post the DAX of your measures, some suggestions:

- Remove the 0's in your source data. Not sure if you have access to the data, but you can replace the 0's with null/blank values in either PowerQuery or SQL.
- We can't see the source data (what does the data in the fact table look like?), but i'm guessing that's where the real 'problem' lies.
- Make an adjustment to the measure. Not the most beautiful solution, but it works. pseudo code:

```
VAR _Show = COUNT ( 'Fact'[ID] )
RETURN
IF ( _Show = 0 , BLANK(), _Show)
```

But, again, we need more info about the data in your fact table and the measures you already created.

---

Edit:

You already replaced BLANKS with 0, and set the 'Show items with no data' on. Then the measure above will do no good.

Suggestion:

- Turn 'Show items with no data' off!

**New measure:**

(assumtion that DimStatus[Description] is on the column

```
# Count = 
// Orginal Measure: Count Unique IDs
VAR __COUNTROSTER = DISTINCTCOUNT('FactJobClubOrientation'[RosterID])

// Second Measuse: Count Regardless of show or no show, to see if there was a session
VAR __COUNTALLROSTER = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('FactJobClubOrientation'[RosterID]), ALL('DimStatus'[Description]))

RETURN
// If there was a sesssion, show the measure with 0 instead of blanks
IF ( __COUNTALLROSTER > 0 , IF ( ISBLANK(__COUNTROSTER) , 0 , __COUNTROSTER))
```

---

**Third suggestion:**

You want to show all the location with 0, if there ar no shows. I've include an ISINSCOPE check for DimDate, to prevent it's showing 0 when collapsing the location.

```
# Count = 
// Orginal Measure: Count Unique IDs
VAR __COUNTROSTER = DISTINCTCOUNT('FactJobClubOrientation'[RosterID])

// Second Measuse: Count Regardless of show or no show, to see if there was a session
VAR __COUNTALLROSTER = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('FactJobClubOrientation'[RosterID]), ALL('DimStatus'[Description]))

// Third: Show 0 for all locations, if there's no session.
VAR __NOROSTER = IF ( NOT ISINSCOPE('DimDate'[SessionDate]) , CALCULATE( 0 , ALL(DimLocation)))

RETURN
// If there was a sesssion, show the measure with 0 instead of blanks
IF ( __COUNTALLROSTER > 0 , IF ( ISBLANK(__COUNTROSTER) , 0 , __COUNTROSTER), __NOROSTER)
```

Comment: Hi TJ_

Thanks for the suggestions.

DAX (Measure): DistinctRosterCount:= IF(CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(FactJobClubOrientation[RosterID])) = BLANK(), 0, CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(FactJobClubOrientation[RosterID])))

This is the DAX behind for displaying the values in the Matrix.

I can’t replace the 0 in DAX with blank or null because as per the business i have to display 0 in Power BI even though the distinct count is null for a location. 

So I placed your suggested DAX, which resulted blank instead of 0. But the problem is how to display 0’s in place of blank?

Comment: Need a bit more info about the data to help you. Can you post a data sample, from the fact table, which includes the involved columns? ShowOrNoShowId, LocationID, SessionDateKey & RosterID?

Comment: Wait a minute: did you turn on 'Show items with no data' AND you replaced BLANKS() with 0?

Comment: Yes, I right clicked and turned on "Show Items with no data" for the matrix in PBI. I attached the Sample fact table data in the main question.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated my answer. Q: what's on the columns?

Comment: In Matrix, on the rows, I am displaying Location from DimLocation table, SessionDate from DimDate table. On the Columns, displaying Description from the DimStatus table (Both Show & NoShow), on the values, I am displaying measure DistinctRosterCount wrote in the Fact table.

Comment: Then, I think my new measure could work. You're not doing anything with the IsShow and IsNoShow in the fact table right?

Comment: I can't say that issue is fully resolved. I attached the two new images 1) January 2) June. When January selected it works fine, When June selected as there are no sessions, all the locations have to show 0's. But it is not. I am not considering ISShow, IsNoShow in the fact table at all. Is it something with the session date in the DimDate table?

Comment: Oke, so if I'm correct: You allways want to see all locations, and if there is a session you want to see the dates. If there's no session: display 0.

Comment: Exactly. you got my point.Thanks for bearing with me. I am very new to Power BI. So it's kinda confusing to me.

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a new suggestion. Keep in mind: this is 'nasty' DAX, to change the behaviour of the matrix. I've not tested for performance.

Comment: Wow. It worked. Looks like SSAS tabular (1200 compatibility) wont support ISINSCOPE. So i changed it to HASONEVALUE and it worked. No doubt you are a MASTER in DAX. This realized Marco and Alberto's words "DAX is simple, but it is not easy".  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! HASONEVALUE has a bit different goal, I think it's better to use ISFILTERED  if ISINSCOPE isn't available.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks @TJ_

Comment: Hey TJ_, when you have time, can you plz help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306031/conditional-formatting-for-multiple-columns-issue

Comment: Hi @TJ_, I need your help with this issue again. As ISINSCOPE is not available in my SSAS, PBI, i replaced it with HASONEVALUE and it worked fine so far as the session da tes are always <> 1. Now i got a situation, for JULY i have one session date and 0 RosterCount. The visual is displaying nothing on this scenario. I tried even COUNTROWS(Values) function. This also didn't helped me out. My PBI may 2020 version is not supporting ISINSCOPE (throwing an error), no idea why.  Are there any other possible solutions?

Comment: I have added a power bi [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68508410/6854117) can you please see it  ?