# Conditional formatting for multiple columns issue

Tags: powerbi, dax, conditional-formatting, powerbi-desktop

I am new to Power BI. Some one please provide me a solution for the following issue.

I have a double heading matrix where customers are in Rows, two columns Status and Description are in the columns section (Both columns are from same lookup table), and a measure in the values section which will display the distinct count in the matrix. Following is the DAX.

DistinctRoster:= IF(CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(FactStatus[RosterId])) = BLANK(), 0, CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(FactStatus[RosterId])))

The matrix is like

[Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i2VR.png)

[Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyphA.png)

Issue: I have to implement background color for column Active placements based on column Placed Duration in Fact table and for column Pending based on  column Pending Duration in fact table.

I added background color for column Active Placements by going to conditional formatting --> Format By rules--> and BAsed on field. It worked great for that column.

[Image-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OdVX.png)

But how i can implement the background color for column Pending? I got stuck at this point.

TIA.

Comment: So you're using one measure in the matrix, and want to use two different columns/values for the conditional formatting?

Comment: Yes you are right.is it possible?

Comment: Yes, with a small hack;) What are the threshold values for the two measures? Are they the same? For example > 80 = red?

Comment: Threshold values are different. For Column Active placements, if the column PlacedDuration in the fact table is 
• In between 150 and 180 then Yellow,
• >180 then Red
For Pending, if the column PendingDuration in the fact table is 
• In between 45 and 60 then Yellow,
• >60 then Red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to apply different conditional column formatting in a matrix that is based on one measure, you could built a supportive measure, on which you'll apply the conditional formatting.

Suppose the field in the column of the matrix is 'Table'[Description], two possibles values: "Value 1" & "Value 2" and your measures are [Measure 1] and [Measure 2].

To 'know' which measure to use for the formatting, you use the SELECTEDVALUE() function.

```
[Measure for formatting] =
VAR __SELECTED =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Description] )
RETURN
    SWITCH ( __SELECTED, 
    "Value 1", [Measure 1], 
    "Value 2", [Measure 2], 0 )
```

Translated: If there's Value 1 on the column, pick Measure 1, if Value 2 on the colum, pick Measure 2. Otherwise: 0 (important for total formatting!)

Now comes the tricky part: if the threshold values for both measures are in the same range, you must add a number/mutiplier to the value, to seperate the formatting.

So do something like:

```
[Measure for formatting] =
VAR __SELECTED =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Description] )
RETURN
    SWITCH ( __SELECTED, 
    "Value 1", [Measure 1], 
    "Value 2", [Measure 2] + 100000, 0 )
```

Now you can build your rules:

- 0 = no formatting (totals)
- range 1 to <100000 = formatting for Value/Measure1
- range >= 100000 = formatting for Value/Measure2

(so greater than 80 becomes greater than 100080 for measure 2)